# why transient variable's state is stored in singleton object?

Tags: java, static, singleton, transient

```
package p1;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.ObjectStreamException;
import java.io.Serializable;


public class SerializationCheck {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        SingletonCompanyCEO s1 = SingletonCompanyCEO.getSingleObject();
        SingletonCompanyCEO s2 = SingletonCompanyCEO.getSingleObject();
        System.out.println("s1==s2:"+(s1==s2));

        ObjectOutputStream obs = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("file.txt"));
        obs.writeObject(s1);

        //first read from file
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("file.txt"));
        SingletonCompanyCEO ceo = (SingletonCompanyCEO)ois.readObject();

        //second read from file 
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("file.txt"));
        SingletonCompanyCEO ceo1 = (SingletonCompanyCEO)ois.readObject();

        System.out.println("ceo==ceo1:"+(ceo==ceo1)+" (read from file ie. de-serialized )");
        System.out.println(ceo1);


    }
}

class SingletonCompanyCEO implements Serializable
{
    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Object readResolve() throws ObjectStreamException {
        return singleObject;
    }
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private transient int age = 55; // age should set to zero by default as age is transient. But it is not happening, any reason?
    private String name ="Amit";
    float salary = 0f;

    private static SingletonCompanyCEO singleObject;
    private SingletonCompanyCEO()
    {
        if(singleObject!=null)
        {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
    }
    public static SingletonCompanyCEO getSingleObject()
    {
        if(singleObject==null)
        {
            singleObject = new SingletonCompanyCEO();
        }
        return singleObject;
    }
    public String toString()
    {
        return name+" is CEO of the company and his age is "+
        age+"(here 'age' is transient variable and did not set to zero while serialization)";
    }
}
```

copy and paste this code in eclipse editor.
What is the reason where 'age' `transient` variable is not set to zero by default while serialization?
Serialization says that transient and static variable are set to zero(or default values) while serialization.

 After de-serialization I am getting `age = 55` instead of `age = 0`. 
There must be reason behind this in JLS. What is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any time a SingletonCompanyCEO object is deserialized, all information obtained from the ObjectInputStream is discarded and instead your singleObject is returned, due to your `readResolve` method.  singleObject is itself an instance which was created using the constructor, not deserialization, so its age is 55.

Answer (score 1):

You are providing a static `SingletonCompanyCEO` object using `getSingleObject`method. So your following reference variables of `SingletonCompanyCEO` i.e `s1` , `s2` are sharing the same `SingletonCompanyCEO` object. For this unique object you have following value for fields:

```
age = 55; 
name ="Amit";
salary = 0f;
```

But you have also overridden `readResolve` method in `SingletonCompanyCEO` class where you are returning the same object to which `s1` and `s2` are referencing. So while deserializing the class JVM makes the variable `ceo` and `ceo1` to reference the same object to which `s1` and `s2` are referencing. So basically you have a single object of `SingletonCompanyCEO` class before serialization and after deserialization. That's why the `age` is printing as `55` .

**UPDATE:**
Here are the steps that is involving in your code after `readResolve` is removed in your code :

1. JVM reads the Object from "file.txt"
   After object is read JVM looks for `readResolve` method in class `SingletonCompanyCEO`.
   JVM does not find `readResolve` and returns the **new object** to `ceo`as returned by deserialization.
2. JVM again reads the object from "file.txt".
   After object is read JVM looks for `readResolve` method in class `SingletonCompanyCEO`.
   JVM does not find `readResolve` and returns the **new object** to `ceo1` as returned by deserialization.

> Hence after two deserialization you have two new objects of
>   `SingletonCompanyCEO`.
>  
>   => ceo==ceo1 returns false.
>   **NOTE**: In both newly created objects value of `age` will be 0 as specified by JLS.

**UPDATE2**
if you comment `writeobject` parts of code and deserialize the class using already existing file (`file.txt`) Then following steps takes place while deserialization:

1. JVM reads the object from the file using ObjectInputStream. 
   After the object is read JVM looks for `readResolve()` method in `SingletonCompanyCEO` class. JVM returns only that object to the variable which is returned by `readResolve()` method defined in class.
2. JVM finds the `readResolve()` method. In `readResolve()` method you had returned `singleObject` which is `null` for now as the method `getSingleObject()` is still not called up. And for your information, the constructor of class is also not called while deserialization , else it would have thrown `IllegalstateException` as you have done in constructor.
3. Since `readResolve()` is returning `null` Hence JVM is also returning `null` . Consequenty `ceo1` and `ceo2` both are `null` .

Comment: Agree. Execute above code then remove code for s1 and s2 reference creation and also remove code for writing object. Now we have serialized file containing object.
After removing, we have only file reading code. Now I found object is not getting created 'null' is returning after reading file. Now again try removing readResolve() then you will find objects are being created and those are not singleton. What is it?

Comment: Ok. Agree. But if we keep readResolve() method then object is coming 'null' from the file. How is it?
How to deserialize Singleton object so that we will get only only instance per JVM?

If we keep readResolve() two objects are created and if we don't keep readResolve() then no objects are created.

Comment: @ Vishal K :-  Again agree. Thanks. Now how do we manage a code to get singleton object of SingletonCompanyCEO Class? if we remove readResolve() then two different objects are created which we don't wan't in programming?

Answer (score 0):

```
private transient int age = 55;
```

When you define a value at declaration, this takes priority.